# Crossover in differential evolution for separable and non-separable functions

Tags: evolutionary-algorithms

This article "[Enhancing Differential Evolution Utilizing Eigenvector-Based Crossover Operator](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6698290/)" said for a non-separable function traditional crossover algorithm are not suitable and they can not diversify the population sufficiently, so the differential evolution stops at the local optimum points. Why does this behavior not hold for separable functions but it exists for non-separable functions? Which key feature of the non-separable functions cause this behavior?